# Convertir .xml a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm loading an Excel file and with the SheetJS library I convert it into a JSON, but I receive it this way:

> JSON.parse(output)

```
data: Array(15)
0: (11) ["id", "created", "device", "plataforma", "locale", "first_render_time", "total_load_time", "total_size", "load_without_js", "request", "score"]
1: (11) ["424", "2019-11-19T23:58:07.977Z", "mobile", "PSI", "es-CO", "9840", "37602", "6286909", "3978", "227", "0"]
2: (11) ["423", "2019-11-19T23:57:43.340Z", "desktop", "PSI", "es-CO", "1981", "7903", "5424580", "3452", "204", "0.19"]
3: (11) ["422", "2019-11-19T23:55:24.163Z", "mobile", "PSI", "es-CO", "10052", "38450", "5850544", "3506", "231"
```

The first row must be the JSON `name`.

I want to receive it this way.

```
[
  {
    id: 6049,
    created: "2019-11-29T20:05:22.870Z",
    device: "desktop",
    plataforma: "PSI",
    locale: "es-CO",
    first_render_time: 2042,
    total_load_time: 7904,
    total_size: 6000627,
    load_without_js: 3722,
    request: 212,
    score: "0.18"
  },
  {
    id: 6046,
    created: "2019-11-29T20:00:23.317Z",
    device: "desktop",
    plataforma: "PSI",
    locale: "es-CO",
    first_render_time: 2052,
    total_load_time: 7974,
    total_size: 6001442,
    load_without_js: 3648,
    request: 212,
    score: "0.18"
  }
]
```

Comment: So write a loop...

Comment: I thought there was some more recursive way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the header (1st row) from the body (all other rows) by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) the array. Iterate the body using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and then [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the header to an object, and take the data from the current array:

```js
const convertToObjects = ([header, ...body]) =>
  body.map(arr => header.reduce((r, prop, i) => {
    r[prop] = arr[i];
    
    return r;
  }, {}));

const data = [
  ["id", "created", "device", "plataforma", "locale", "first_render_time", "total_load_time", "total_size", "load_without_js", "request", "score"],
  ["424", "2019-11-19T23:58:07.977Z", "mobile", "PSI", "es-CO", "9840", "37602", "6286909", "3978", "227", "0"],
  ["423", "2019-11-19T23:57:43.340Z", "desktop", "PSI", "es-CO", "1981", "7903", "5424580", "3452", "204", "0.19"]
];

const result = convertToObjects(data);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert data like that

```
data.map((a,i)=> Object.fromEntries(data[0].map((x,j)=> [x,data[i][j]])) ).slice(1)
```

```js
data = [ ["id", "created", "device", "plataforma", "locale", "first_render_time", "total_load_time", "total_size", "load_without_js", "request", "score"],
["424", "2019-11-19T23:58:07.977Z", "mobile", "PSI", "es-CO", "9840", "37602", "6286909", "3978", "227", "0"],
["423", "2019-11-19T23:57:43.340Z", "desktop", "PSI", "es-CO", "1981", "7903", "5424580", "3452", "204", "0.19"],
["422", "2019-11-19T23:55:24.163Z", "mobile", "PSI", "es-CO", "10052", "38450", "5850544", "3506", "231"]];

result= data.map((a,i)=> Object.fromEntries(data[0].map((x,j)=> [x,data[i][j]])) ).slice(1);

console.log(result);
```